# using csv as a value python

Tags: csv, python-3.7

I'm still green in programing and trying to ajust and learn python but I am struggling with reading a csv file and using the content of the file as a value property

I have looked and googled to death and all the solutions puts out 
['Deon:app2018:value:1538402685271'] ore a virtical result

example:
session = file content of csv

here is the closes i got
Code:

```
import urllib.request
import csv

with open('F:\test\session\main\data\credentials\session_id.csv','r') as file:
    session_ID = csv.reader(file)
    for row in session_ID:
       session = "".join(row)
       print(session)

url = 'http://webrates.app.com/rates/connect.html?id='+session 
print(url)
```

**What i get**

Deon:app2018:value:1538402685271

http://webrates.app.com/rates/connect.html?id=

**What i want**

Deon:app2018:value:1538402685271

http://webrates.app.com/rates/connect.html?id=Deon:app2018:value:1538402685271

Kind Regards
Deon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after lots of trail and error

this solved my problem

```
import csvlib.request
import csv

with open('F:\test\session\main\data\credentials\session_id.csv','r') as file:
    id = file.read() + '\n'

url = 'http://webrates.app.com/rates/connect.html?id='+ id
print(url)
```